# Redirect a page and load/refresh a div within that page using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirect, partial-page-refresh

I am using ajax to redirect to a page by window.location = "page.php"

After the page is redirected I need to load a div within that page. For example search.php.

I have been reading up on how to do this and from what I gather you can do this by using **jquery**. I have never used **jquery** so if someone can help me out I will really appreciate it.

If it can be done without **jquery** even better!

Edit: Let me explain again what I am trying to do. I have a table that updates that the db. All of it is done through php, js and ajax.

For example "Displaytable.php" displays the table. The user can search and it replaces the search result in a div. When someone wants to update it goes to update.php. After it's updated i want to redirect the page to Displaytable.php with the search results in the div. I am using session variables to do the search. The search works fine i have tested it in another page.

Comment: Can you just not include the page include "mypage.php"; or use an iframe?

Comment: JavaScript window.location = "page.php" is not an AJAX call. What difficulties are you having with loading HTML after a page redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is what you are looking for (using jQuery):

In `page.php`:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
    $("#divID").load('search.php');
});
//]]</script>
```

**Description:**
This will load the page `search.php` into the (`div`) element with id, `"divID"` after `page.php` has been loaded.

Comment: Yes something like that. Let me try it. Any way to add a flag to load the search on a certain event or a flag. I don't want the search to display all the time, only when it's redirected from update.php and another page.

Comment: That worked thanks a bunch!!! Now I need to figure out how to add a flag. Any ideas? So basically when I first go to page.php and there are no search results so nothing should be displayed. Now it's giving me a undefined variable from php which is expected as the variables are not set in search.php

Comment: Remove the code block when you don't want to load the search. You have full flexibility at the server end. You can check the `Referer` header to know, from which page, has the user been redirected.

Comment: Couldn't get what you mean. :(

Comment: From my last comment? The original problem is sort of resolved. It now redirects the page and refreshes the div. But it does that every single time the page is loaded. I only want to call that function when a page is redirected.

Comment: I figured it out. I put the jquery command in a function and I am calling it when required. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is written in JavaScript, so you can always do without jQuery if you write it yourself--a matter of brevity though.

Seems you are trying to continue controlling the window after you have loaded another page into it. You can't do this if you are changing the current window's location (though, if the page in question is in the same domain (e.g., if both pages are on www.example.com). (You can if you are opening another window or adding a page within the current page.)

If the redirected page is under your control, you can load a div asynchronously (look for a tutorial on Ajax--though jQuery does offer a convenient, well-tested, cross-browser approach which may be more cumbersome on your own) by adding an onload event in the opened page and populating the div at that point.

Comment: I am loading it asynchronously and the redirected page is within the same domain so it works.